# Accessing current authenticated users info

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have a lambda function that is triggered whenever a user uploads an image to an S3 bucket. I'm trying to write the generated url of that image to a DynamoDB database along with the email of the user who uploaded said image, which should be the user that is currently logged in.

I've gotten these attributes before by doing

```
event.request.userAttributes.email
```

But that was done in a Cognito triggered post-confirmation lambda function, so that information was stored in the **event** parameter of the handler function. In this scenario, I'm not sure if that information is sent along in the event. Any idea how I'd get access to information like that? I've been reading up JWT ID Tokens, but I haven't figured out how to access that or if that's the correct and safe approach.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you will have to handle it yourself. One option which you may like is to use custom object metadata to store the information about the uploading user:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html

You can then retrieve the metadata together with the object and continue from that point.

Comment: Surely there must be some way to know who is currently logged in? The metadata approach you suggested could be used but I still don't know who is logged in, so I have no actual metadata to pass.

Comment: "logged in" can have meaning in your application but it does not have any meaning from the AWS viewpoint. They check only if the api is called with a valid signature and if the IAM user has permission to invoke the given action.